# Unable to show tooltip on marquee using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip, marquee

I have coded this, but it's not loading the tooltip when I go to marquee text.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.webringideas.com/wp-content/uploads/demo/tooltip/js/ntip.js"></script>

<div id="fixedfooter">
    <marquee class="smooth_m" behavior="scroll" direction="left" onMouseOut="this.start()" onMouseOver="this.stop()" scrollamount="3">
        <div id="demo">

  <span style="color: #ff0000;" class="formInfo">
  <a href="#">
  <span style="color: #000000;display: none;" class="mycontent">test Successful for HTML Tooltip on marquee</span></a>Testing HTML Tooltip on marquee using jQuery and css
  </span>

  </div>
    </marquee>
</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".formInfo").tooltip({tooltipcontentclass:"mycontent"})
});;
        </script>
```

However, the same thing works fine, when I am not using marquee, and text is static.

This works fine with this,

```
<span class="formInfo">Tooltip<span style="display: none;" class="mycontent">Testing <font color="red">HTML</font> content</span></span>
```

Is there any tooltip you can recommend which I can use in my Marquee?
Thanks!

Comment: I have also tried http://www.jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.html, but I want tooltip to be like, when I remove my mouse cursor from the marquee text, the tooltip get hide automatically

Comment: `<3 Marquee`. Haven't seen this for couple of years. You do know this is deprecated since long long time?

Comment: then, what else I can use to do what functionality i want. With onmouse over, the moving text will stop, and on mouseout, it will start again.

Comment: this is working. http://jsfiddle.net/egh5E/

Comment: Use one of the thousand plugin available for jQuery like http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/ or http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm#example

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little, and it looks like working on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egh5E/).

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.webringideas.com/wp-content/uploads/demo/tooltip/js/ntip.js"></script>
<div id="fixedfooter">
<marquee class="smooth_m" behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseout="this.start()" onmouseover="this.stop()" scrollamount="3">
<div id="demo">
    <span style="color: #ff0000;" class="formInfo">
    <div class="mycontent" style="color: #000000;display:none;">
        test Successful for HTML Tooltip on marquee
    </div>
    <a href="#"></a>Testing HTML Tooltip on marquee using jQuery and css</span>
</div>
</marquee>
</div>
```

The javascript part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".formInfo").tooltip({
        tooltipcontentclass: "mycontent"
    })
});;
```

Comment: thanks a lot tpaksu. I am getting one undesired error in this, here is the screen-snapshot http://i.imgur.com/SWquB.jpg . When I mouse-over the marquee-text, the tooltip foes to very right (not visible on visible screen) (Please see the image in bottom). I think there may be some alignment error in http://www.webringideas.com/wp-content/uploads/demo/tooltip/js/ntip.js

Comment: I'm not familiar with ntip, but there's a line : `jQuery('#NT').css({left: clickElementx+"px", top: clickElementy+"px"});` in the ntip.js file which defines the position of it. You can play with that.